# How do I call a Spring controller method with Jquery AJAX

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I have the following Spring Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/accreq")
```

with the following mapping

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/defRoles", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String loadDefaultRoles(
    @RequestParam(value="idGroup", required=false) String groupID
    throws ServletException{
```

I'm trying to call this method with the following jquery ajax

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: '/accreq/defRoles',
data: {idGroup: $('#infoGroup').val() },
success: function() {
    alert("success");
    }
});
```

Please help me figure out why the Spring method is not being called even though the ajax method is being called when I click a button.  I have stepped through the script with firebug and it definitely hits the ajax function.

Comment: firebug should also show the full ajax request, make sure it is hitting the full url you intend to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, try to see what happens if you hit the URL manually in the browser

If that is successful, turn on request tracking in firebug and see if firefox actually hits the URL (and what the response says)

Answer (score 1):

try to add this to your jquery

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("error:" + textStatus + " exception:" + errorThrown);
    }
}
```

and you will see if an error occurs

Answer (score 1):

which pattern are you using in your web.xml? Search for the  tag and see which pattern are you using.

For example, if you are using:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

you should use something like this:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: '/accreq/defRoles.html',
data: {idGroup: $('#infoGroup').val() },
success: function() {
    alert("success");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that there is a server side exception occurring and that is why you are not seeing a response. If you have debugging on make sure your exceptions are thrown and/or you have a log of the same.

Also your comment is kinda ambiguous what do u mean the spring methid is not being called even though the ajax methid is being called. Can you please clarify. Also waht would help is the firebug  o/p of the call with a screenshot or seomthing.. also if firebug throws an error what error it is.