# Using AJAX through Javascript to call a spring controller

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I ain't able to open the controller's method

```
var url = "UsersGroupReader";
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
req.onreadystatechange = processAccessGroupRequest;
req.open("GET", url, true); 
req.send(null);
```

My *controller* is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "UsersGroupReader", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Vector<String> readUsersGroup(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpSession httpSession) {
```

The `req.status` I am receiving is `404` through `AJAX`.

The pattern in my *web.xml* is as follows:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I tried using `UsersGroupReader.html` in both the `AJAX` function and the controller but still unable to access the controller.

Can anyone help me spot the mistake?
Could be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909580/how-do-i-call-a-spring-controller-method-with-jquery-ajax), in vain even after following it.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `var url = "/UsersGroupReader.html";`

Comment: @Quoi I tried that too. It didn't work.

Comment: install firebug plugin in mozila and debug it. Believe me it makes your life easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that the request you are sending is either not being received by the intended server or that the DispatcherServlet is not being invoked for the request. To troubleshoot these type of issues you can usually find the actual cause by:

1. Use your browser's developer toolbar to determine the exact URL being sent in the request.
2. Turn up Spring's logging to debug to find out what it is doing when it receives the request (*if* it receives the request).
3. Adjust the servlet-mapping accordingly.

Comment: I checked the URL and I found my mistake. I missed the query string which proved vital. Thank you